# Why Bionic C runtime library in Android does not support "%n" format in printf function?

Tags: c, bionic

According to ISO C standard (ISO/IEC 9899), `printf` function contains "`%n`" format to count the number of output characters.

> n: The argument shall be a pointer to signed integer into which is written the
> number of characters written to the output stream so far by this call to
> `fprintf`. No argument is converted, but one is consumed. If the conversion
> specification includes any flags, a field width, or a precision, the behavior is
> undefined.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int c1, c2;
    printf ("hello%n, world%n\n", &c1, &c2);
    printf ("% d\t% d\n", c1, c2);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output of the example]

The C runtime library on both Windows (MSVCRT/UCRT) and Linux (GLIBC) supports "`%n`" format in `printf` function. (However, "`%n`" format is disabled by default when using cl.exe to compile C program in Windows. A nonstandard function `_set_printf_count_output` by Microsoft is required to enable "`%n`" format. That is because cl.exe is a C++ compiler, function `printf` is not in common use in C++ [In C++ `std::cout` is used instead]. If cl.exe followed C standard, "`%n`" format should be enabled by default and disabled by using `_set_printf_count_output` function. In addition, Microsoft creates a nonstandard function `printf_s`, in which "`%n`" format is completely disabled)

Unlike MSVCRT/UCRT in Windows and GLIBC in Linux, The Bionic C runtime library in Android does not support "`%n`" format at all, which parses "`%n`" format only into two ordinary characters "`%`" and "`n`". Why "`%n`" format is not parsed in ISO standard by Bionic C runtime library?

Comment: Likely because `%n` has been the source of a great many exploits in programs, and is rarely used.

Comment: In MSVC [Microsoft says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-160#type) *The `n` specifier is disabled by default; for information see the important security note.*.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Just post the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: @WeatherVane cl.exe is a C++ compiler. `printf` is not commonly used in C++ because C++ has `std::cout`. So Microsoft does not need to fully support C standard in cl.exe.

Comment: @stanchcorder6 CL is a C compiler. I use it all the time, but don't code in C++ although CL might work for C++ too. I was pointing out that `%n` isn't freely usable.

Comment: @WeatherVane `int n; scanf ("%d", &n); int a[n];` does not have any error in C. But cl.exe generates an error "Expression must have a constant value" even with /tc switch and file extension is .c. (GCC and Clang does not give any errors or warnings)

Comment: @stanchcorder6 that is `scanf` not `printf` and didn't use `%n` anyway. The compiler error is referring to `int a[n];` because MS VC does not support variable length arrays.